# Linq2XML build XDocument by using a list in a list, stackoverflowexception

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml, stack-overflow

I am trying to create an XML that looks like this:

```
<RootList>
    <Root>
        <ID>value1</ID>
        <Number>value2</Number>
        <Quantity>value3</Quantity>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <ID>value1</ID>
        <Number>value2</Number>
        <Quantity>value4</Quantity>
    </Root>
    <Root>
        <ID>value5</ID>
        <Number>value6</Number>
        <Quantity>value7</Quantity>
    </Root>
</RootList>
```

By using instances of the interfaces below.

```
interface IRoot
{
    int ID { get; }
    string Number { get; set; }
    List<IQuantity> List { get; set; }
}

interface IQuantity
{
    int QuantityID { get; }
    double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The code below is what I use to create the XML, however the process is being terminated due to stackoverflowexception.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("RootList",
        this._list.Select(root =>
            root.List.Select(quantity =>
                new XElement("Root", 
                    new XElement("ID", root.ID.ToString()),
                    new XElement("Number", root.Number),
                    new XElement("Quantity", quantity.Quantity.ToString())
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

If I remove the inner Select (where i iterate through the list within the list) the output works. I have no idea how to actually trace this error but i'm certain it is due to the inner select. Has anyone else had the same problem, or have any tips regarding this? :)

Comment: Well you are out of memory from using the inner select.  How big are these Lists typically?

Comment: Created a function to loop through them : With the current dataset the List<IRoot>.Count = 2 and each IRoot has 5 IQuantities in them. So the data shouldn't be that much of a deal. I reduced the return the the repositories to just return 2 Roots and 5 Quantities per call.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue now, I left some XElements out of the question since i thought they were unnecessary, however under the first child-node to root were going to have a class variable as its value. I made a private static Guid _guid out of it and now it works. I beg your pardon.